# Recommended ASP.NET Grid and UI tools

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

We are building a web application using C# and SQL server.  We are thinking about buying the DevExpress ASP.NET controls.  Anybody have any opinions about this tool or have any they would recommend?

Comment: From heresay I hear the devexpress controls (web) are more hassle than they are worth, however I have had good experiences with the windows forms controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made extensive use of the DevExpress ASPxGridView and many of their other controls.

As mentioned earlier, the DevExpress controls can create a lot of markup, however, they other a ton of functionality and features.  They're pretty easy to use.  If all you're needing is a really simple grid control, then it's probably overkill.  However, if you want to have features like sorting/grouping, drag-drop re-ordering of columns, hiding and adding columns at run-time, AJAX support, etc. then these controls are awesome.

Recent versions (2009.2 and 2009.3) have introduced a number of performance improvements mainly around reducing the volume of traffic and cycle time involved in round-trips to the server.  This has made the controls feel even snappier at the end-user side.

One other key benefit of the DevExpress controls is the support.  These guys are excellent at getting back to you with meaningful answers to questions in a timely manner.  I also enjoy the fact that they have several releases per year which include enhancements and new functionality.  You can see their release history by looking at their release history for the ASPxGridView:  http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/whatsnew.xml

All in all, I think it's a good value for the money.

By the way, I have no affiliation with DevExpress, I'm just a happy customer.

Comment: +1: good tools, to be sure, but their support really sets them apart.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the DevExpress control, but as you were also asking for alternatives:

I was mainly using [Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) in the past. This is a full suite of controls with many controls (have a look at the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) to get an idea). I think these controls are quite powerful, although you'll need to consult the documentation to take advantage of all the features. In addition, I'd like to point out that telerik offers great support (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

i think the tool is good, but if you are just starting the building of the application i would recommend using asp.net mvc instead of asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

I used the DevExpress grid controls on a project and they were excellent.  Easy to skin and customise with some great features out of the box like filtering, sorting and AJAX support.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the **Infragistics WebGrid.** They have great knowledge base and help available from their website.

The feature I liked and implemented was the client side edit of data simulating excel functionality. You can edit the cell by simply moving the arrow keys and without using mouse.

Take a sample look at h[ttp://samples.infragistics.com/2009.2/WebFeatureBrowser/Default.aspx](http://samples.infragistics.com/2009.2/WebFeatureBrowser/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've used both and my honest opinion is that they are over-engineered (esp. Telerik) and create a lot of muck in the markup. Also, there is always a learning curve involved in successfully adopting any of these offerings. However, if you really do have to have the eye candy, go for it:-)

Comment: [Full Disclosure: I work for Telerik.] Telerik tries to minimize any "muck" in our control rendering. All controls render semantic HTML and use CSS completely for styling. There is no ugly "nested tables for layout" in our rendering (unlike some other ASP.NET components). That said, something like the Telerik Grid is a swiss army knife- it can do a lot and thus requires HTML to support features. If you only need to display data, "POHTML" (plain old) is probably best!